# How can I create an Azure AD application using the fluent API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the following code to try to programmatically register an application in Azure Active Directory:

```
        var application = azure.ActiveDirectoryApplications.Define(applicationName)
            .WithSignOnUrl(url)
            .WithIdentifierUrl(url)
            .WithAvailableToOtherTenants(false)
            .DefinePasswordCredential(id)
              .WithPasswordValue(secret)
              .Attach()
            .Create();
```

Where `azure` is an instance of `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure`.

When I run the above to create an Azure Active Directory Application, an `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure` exception is thrown with the message `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`. Creation of other Azure resources (like resource groups and app services) work just fine.

Looking at the exception details, I can see that a request is made to the following endpoint:

`https://graph.windows.net/{myTenantId}/applications?api-version=1.6`

The following is in the response body:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

Since the bodies says "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation", it appears to be a simple permission issue, but I have granted the following permissions (while signed in as a global administrator) for the Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory API for the application that's running the code:

- Access the directory as the signed-in user
- Read and write directory data

Are these privileges not enough? What am I missing? As I said, creation of other resources using the fluent API works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All User.Read` is sufficient permission to create applications in the Azure Active Directory. Since you doesn't provide how you construct the `azure` instance, I would provide a working code sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = "http://adfei.onmicrosoft.com/appFluent";
    var id = "abc";
    var secret = "secret";
    var applicationName = "appFluent";
    var credFile = new AzureCredentials(new UserLoginInformation
    {
        ClientId = "{appId of native application}",
        UserName = "{userName}",
        Password = "{password}"
    },
        "adfei.onmicrosoft.com", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate(credFile).WithDefaultSubscription();
    var application = azure.ActiveDirectoryApplications.Define(applicationName)
    .WithSignOnUrl(url)
    .WithIdentifierUrl(url)
    .WithAvailableToOtherTenants(false)
    .DefinePasswordCredential(id)
      .WithPasswordValue(secret)
      .Attach()
    .Create();

    Console.Read();
}
```

And please ensure the scope is include in the access token to ensure that you have the permission for this operation. You can capture the request via Fiddler to check the token and decode the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to check `scp` claims in the access token.

Comment: Thank you, it works when constructing the IAzure client like you shown. Previously, I was only using the clientId/clientSecret for the application (with manually granted permissions in the Portal) and it was perhaps that which was the problem.

Comment: I constructed the IAzure with clientId/clientSecret and gave the app the right read/write permissions in the portal. This worked for me.

Comment: Is there a lower permission that can be used than `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, i.e. one that does not need admin consent? The user can create app registrations in the portal so it seems like there should be a way. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting `'Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest''` using your sample code where the native application already has Application Administrator role. Any idea?

Comment: @unruledboy normally, 'badrequest' means that you are passing wrong parameters or endpoint, you may double check the corresponding API and code samples

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Tried different combination of parameters still the same issue. How can we get more diagnostics details of the issue, as in why it is considered as bad request?

Comment: @unruledboy, If you are using SDK, have you tried using Fiddler to capture the REST send to server? And you may share more details about this request and response, so the community who are familiar this can help looking into this issue.